# Polymer dart dynamic polymorphic template selection

Tags: dart, polymer

I have

```
class Fruit {}
List<Fruit> fruits;
```

with instances of

```
class Banana extends Fruit {}
class Apple extends Fruit {}
```

Currently, in my polymer element I have methods

```
isBanana(Fruit fruit) => fruit is Banana;
isApple(Fruit fruit) => fruit is Apple;
```

and in my template code

```
<template repeat="{{fruit in fruits}}">
    <template if="{{isBanana(fruit)}}">
        <banana-element></banana-element>
    </template>
    <template if="{{isApple(fruit)}}">
        <apple-element></apple-element>
    </template>
</template>
```

Does Dart polymer natively support above usecase without the boilerplate `isBanana()` and `isApple()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'natively support'

<strike>`<template if="{{fruit is Banana}}">`</strike> doesn't work.

and omit the two methods `isBanana` and `isFruit`.
If this doesn't work I guess your attempt is fine.

Comment: This does not work. By natively supporting, I mean it would work.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet myself. Do you get an error message?

Comment: I built an example to try it myself but the `is` operator is not supported. Also a type name like `Banana` isn't recognized within the expression (`NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'Banana'.`).
You can create a feature request at dartbug.com